# JS & HTML post different table dependand of browser version

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have problem with creating dynamic table which will work in `Internet Explorer 6` because of `json` usage. I actually found nice work around. I want to implement script which will show different `html` table depends on version of the user browser.

 Here is my browser version detector script:

```
<script>
    function getInternetExplorerVersion()
    // Returns the version of Windows Internet Explorer or a -1
    // (indicating the use of another browser).
    {
        var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
            var ua = navigator.userAgent;
            var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
            if (re.exec(ua) != null)
                rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
        }
        return rv;
    }
function checkIEVersion()
{
   var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();
   if ( ver> -1 )
   {
      if ( ver == 6.0 ){
    <? echo"<TABLE id=\"tableToModify\" width=\"1100px\" border=\"1\"  class='list questionaire' width='600'>";
    echo" <TR class='columndesc'>";
    echo"<TD WIDTH=\"50%\">Col1<font color=\"red\">*</font></TD>";
    echo"<TD WIDTH=\"50%\">Col1<font color=\"red\">*</font></TD>";

    echo  "</TABLE>";   ?>     
   }
    echo"<TABLE id=\"tableToModify\" width=\"1100px\" border=\"1\"  class='list questionaire' width='600'>";
    echo" <TR class='columndesc'>";
    echo"<TD WIDTH=\"22%\">Col1<font color=\"red\">*</font></TD>";
    echo"<TD WIDTH=\"22%\">col2<font color=\"red\"></font></TD>";
    echo"<TD WIDTH=\"22%\">col3<font color=\"red\"></font></TD>";
    echo"<TD WIDTH=\"22%\">col4<font color=\"red\">*</font></TD>";
    echo" <TD WIDTH=\"22%\">col5<font color=\"red\">*</font></TD>";
    echo" <TD WIDTH=\"12%\"> col6<font color=\"red\">*</font></TD>";
    echo  "</TABLE>";

?>
}
}
checkIEVersion();
</script>
```

But right now I am getting errorz : `uncaught syntax exception`. I do realise that `php - echo` is the couse but I can't come with another idea especially when I want this table to be showed in the position I want it to be:

```
Some html fields, imput tables buttons forms
```

```
Script I posted above
```

```
other form fields etc
```

to summarize I have `HTML` code above and under the script.
Can anyone give me a hint how to fix my problem?

Comment: i wouldn't mind making a webpage IE6 safe! look at this link http://ie6isolderthanyourgrandpa.com/ also you can use special html tags so that only IE will interpret them

Comment: You don't have an opening or closing for your `if ( ver == 6.0 )` statement for starters. ^^

Comment: `<!--[if IE 6]>
<some IE tag>
<![endif]-->`

Comment: With that edit, you are missing a closing for your function now.  Also, you are echo'ing tables into javascript code. EDIT, also missing your `else` statement that the table `id`'s seem to imply is there.

Comment: Once the page is loaded, Right click your browser and view source code. What I feel is your echo is giving out <Table...> and as it is inside the <script>, it is throwing you the exception. Assign the PHP output to a variable and then write it to the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you need (might need tweaking according to your needs):

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Windows Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
    var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null) rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
    }
    return rv;
}

function checkIEVersion() {
    var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();
    if (ver > -1) {
        if (ver == 6.0) {
            $html = "<TABLE id=\"tableToModify\" width=\"1100px\" border=\"1\"  class='list questionaire' width='600'>" +
            "<TR class='columndesc'>" +
            "<TD WIDTH=\"50%\">Col1<font color=\"red\">*</font></TD>" +
            "<TD WIDTH=\"50%\">Col1<font color=\"red\">*</font></TD>" +
            "</TABLE>";
        } else {
            $html = "<TABLE id=\"tableToModify\" width=\"1100px\" border=\"1\"  class='list questionaire' width='600'>" +
            "<TR class='columndesc'>" +
            "<TD WIDTH=\"22%\">Col1<font color=\"red\">*</font></TD>" +
            "<TD WIDTH=\"22%\">col2<font color=\"red\"></font></TD>" +
            "<TD WIDTH=\"22%\">col3<font color=\"red\"></font></TD>" +
            "<TD WIDTH=\"22%\">col4<font color=\"red\">*</font></TD>" +
            "<TD WIDTH=\"22%\">col5<font color=\"red\">*</font></TD>" +
            "<TD WIDTH=\"12%\"> col6<font color=\"red\">*</font></TD>" +
            "</TABLE>";
        }
        document.write($html);
    }
}
checkIEVersion();
```